# NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException error codes

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, exception

I am developing application in C # with NHibernate and SQLServer. I got this exception:

```
could not update: [MyApp.Client # 94] [SQL: UPDATE [Client] ...
```

The exception is caused by a unique key index in the client code field.

I want to know if exists any reference to the list of error codes nhibernate|hibernate.
Example: #94 --> unique key restriction
I keep getting access `SQLException` to check that it is unique key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I think the number 94 is not an error code, the message is trying to point you to the problematic object causing the error.
By the way is this a web application, you should use Merge instead of update.